# Iterate over two different iterable types with the same item types in a single loop in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-itertools

In a Rust function, I have two different collection types that both contain strings. I need to iterate over one of them with a loop, but the iterator types are different. How would I bring both iterators to a common denominator?

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    run(true);
    run(false);
}

fn run(some_argument: bool) {
    let set: HashSet<String> = (0..4).map(|v| v.to_string()).collect();
    let map: HashMap<String, i32> = (5..9).map(|v| (v.to_string(), v)).collect();

    // this should be a generic non-consuming iterator over &String (or &str?) values
    let iter = if some_argument {
        &set.iter()
    } else {
        &map.keys()
    };

    for v in iter {
        println!("{v}");
    }
}
```

P.S. Bonus: what if one of the collection types stores `&str` instead of `String` - can that be done without significant reallocations/complexities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solutions which can achieve similar functionality to what you are looking for

1. Using a Box as the iterator

```rs
fn run(some_argument: bool) {
    let set: HashSet<String> = (0..4).map(|v| v.to_string()).collect();
    let map: HashMap<String, i32> = (5..9).map(|v| (v.to_string(), v)).collect();

    let iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=&String>> = if some_argument {
        Box::new(set.iter())
    } else {
        Box::new(map.keys())
    };

    for v in iter {
        println!("{v}");
    }
}
```

2. Moving the iterator logic to another function

```rs
fn run(some_argument: bool) {
    let set: HashSet<String> = (0..4).map(|v| v.to_string()).collect();
    let map: HashMap<String, i32> = (5..9).map(|v| (v.to_string(), v)).collect();

    if some_argument {
        print(&mut set.iter());
    } else {
        print(&mut map.keys());
    }
}

fn print(iter: &mut dyn Iterator<Item=&String>) {
    for v in iter {
        println!("{v}");
    }
}
```